# How is it possible to stretch native ads over all columns within a Grid-RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridview, gridlayoutmanager, native-ads

I´m using a 2-column GridView based on the RecyclerView in my app.

Now I want to embed native ads. When I do that, native ads get cropped into a single column, but I actually want to have the natives beeing stretched over all columns up to their original size.

[image]
To visualize what I mean, I´ve attached an example. This is the Lovoo app

**How can this be done with the RecyclerView?**

Comment: try setting `setSpanSizeLookup ` in gridlayout manager

Answer (score 2):

According to Vipul Asri´s hint, I´ve found something which works

```
final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);

        gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                switch (listAdapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                    case ViewType.DEFAULT_ITEM_TYPE:
                        return 1;
                    case ViewType.AD_ITEM_TYPE:
                        return gridLayoutManager.getSpanCount();
                    default:
                        return -1;
                }
            }
        });
```

and in your adapter something like this

```
   @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isAd(position))
            return ViewType.AD_ITEM_TYPE;
        return ViewType.DEFAULT_ITEM_TYPE;
    }
```